# substring utf-8 characters with alphanumeric character up to 10 words

Tags: php, substring, multibyte, mbstring

I have a problem with getting a substring of this string:

```
GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSocialに対応したSNSの「OpenPNE」をインストールしたので、今回はソーシャルアプリを作ってOpenPNE上で公開してみます。また、作ったアプリをmixiアプリとしてmixiにも登録してみましょう。
```

I just wanted to display up to nth character or at least does not display broken/incomplete words.

at first i tried.

```
$content = "GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSocialに対応したSNSの「OpenPNE」をインストールしたので、今回はソーシャルアプリを作ってOpenPNE上で公開してみます。また、作ったアプリをmixiアプリとしてmixiにも登録してみましょう。";
$content = mb_substr($content, 0, 10, 'UTF-8');
```

but it results to:

```
GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSo
```

the word is not complete

i also tried using regex:

```
$content = "GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSocialに対応したSNSの「OpenPNE」をインストールしたので、今回はソーシャルアプリを作ってOpenPNE上で公開してみます。また、作ったアプリをmixiアプリとしてmixiにも登録してみましょう。";
if (preg_match('/^.{1,40}\b/s', $content, $match))
{
    print_r($match);
}
```

resulted to:

```
Array ( [0] =>GMO )
```

what could have been done to get something like

```
GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSocial
```

word should be complete. is there an mb_ function in php i could use to accomplish this?

Comment: "Word boundary" in Japanese is not a trivial concept... Do you just not want *latin* words to be broken up, or does that apply to the Japanese too?

Comment: Are you sure you got that with length=10?

Comment: @specialscope with mb_ string functions of php at least does not break the word.

Comment: @deceze this will be applied to japanese only.

Comment: The question is, is *"GMOクラウドの芦"* acceptable, or does it need to consider **Japanese word boundaries** as well and return *"GMOクラウドの芦田"*?

Comment: @deceze how do i tell the boudaries in a japanese sentence?

Comment: **That is the question!** Do you need to? Because then the answer will be a lot more complex. Or don't you care about that? Then the answer will be simpler.

Comment: If your requirement is breaking into words you need to use one of the morphological analyzers for japanese. For eg. chasen.

Comment: well. thats complicated. i will tell my client about how difficult it is, and what disadvantages may occur in doing this. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need Morphological Analysis tools such as Mecab to convert string to array. Mecab can be used by command line and [PHP extension](https://github.com/rsky/php-mecab). If you use homebrew, install **mecab** and **mecab-ipadic**.

```
$words = [
  'GMO', 'クラウド', 'の', '芦田', 'です。', '前回、', 
  'OpenSocial', 'に', '対応した', 'SNS'
];

$max = 26;

$ret = '';
$i = 0;

while(mb_strlen($ret.$words[$i], 'UTF-8') <= $max) {

  $ret .= $words[$i];
  $i += 1;
}

var_dump(
  mb_strlen($ret, 'UTF-8'),
  'GMOクラウドの芦田です。前回、OpenSocial' === $ret
);
```